# How do I square a norm in CVX?

Tags: matlab, exponentiation, cvx

In the CVX package for Matlab, I want to minimize a function like $|Ax-b|_2^2$ . Meaning the square of a 2-norm. How do I code that in CVX? I tried both:

```
minimize (norm(A*x-b,2)^2);
```

and

```
minimize (norm(A*x-b,2)*norm(A*x-b,2));
```

but both threw errors. Is there a builtin function I'm supposed to be using?

(Note, really I'm trying to minimize the sum of that norm squared plus another norm like `minimize (norm(A*x-b,2)^2 + norm(x,1));` so that's why I'm trying to specify the norm squared and not just be satisfied with finding the minimum of the norm unsquared.)

Comment: What about [`sum_square_abs( A*x-b )`](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#scalar-quadratic-forms)?  Also, regardless of the success, I'm wondering why you wish to do this; minimization of the norm is a minimization of the norm squared.

Comment: Well the square norm is differentiable, while the norm itself is not. That's a big plus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CVX does not support the `()^2` operator. You can either do

```
(A*x-b)'*(A*x-b)
```

or

```
power(2,norm(A*x-b,2))
```